# Purpose of creating an Azure AD B2C App registration inside a regular Azure AD Tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I was able to create an App registration for Azure AD B2C inside a regular Azure AD Tenant. I was wondering what the purpose would be for this since it cannot be accessed?

The backstory of this is I was unaware that our Tenant could not have both AD and AD B2C, so I had been trying to use this App registration for my Blazor app login page. This does not work. It does not allow you to add User flows!

I since then created a new Tenant and App and that works now. But this App registration pictured here still remains under this AD Tenant (not B2C), seemingly disconnected and useless. What is going on here? Why am I allowed to create it? This App being stuck out here makes me wonder if Apps are actually independent of how they look in the Azure hierarchy and if that is beneficial in some way -- for instance, being able to register it once for many Tenants to reduce deployment/maintenance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure AD applications and Azure AD B2C applications are separate products. They are independent of each other and cannot coexist in the same tenant， you will not see any Azure AD B2C applications in Azure AD tenants. Even if you click the Azure AD B2C tab to create an App registration in a regular Azure AD tenant, the application is not a b2c application, it is still an AAD application, as you can see, it does not allow you to add user flows because it is still an AAD application.

They are distinguished according to their functions.  An Azure AD tenant represents an organization. An Azure AD B2C tenant represents a collection of identities to be used with relying party applications.   Even if you click the Azure AD B2C tab in the regular Azure AD tenant to create an application registration, it can only use the functions in the Azure AD tenant. If you To use the features in Azure AD B2C, you can only register the application in the Azure AD B2C tenant.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: I'll accept the answer, but I believe that is kind of a bug in Azure that it lets you create what looks like a B2C App in a normal AD Tenant.